# AnkhSVN Merging Trunk into Branch

Tags: visual-studio, svn, version-control, ankhsvn

I'm trying to merge changes from a Trunk into a Branch. Previously when I've tried this everything has worked perfectly however in this instance the merge wizard has a cross next to "No uncommitted changes" and will not let me proceed. I've done everything I can think of to resolve this but as I have no entries in my "Pending changes" window I'm at a loss as to what could be the problem!

Any help or guidance on what to try next would be very much appreciated! I'm using Visual Studio 2012 with the latest stable 2.4 AnkhSVN release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR - Downloaded TortoiseSVN and used it and VisualSVN server console to see exactly what was going on.

This was impossible to resolve with AnkhSVN alone. I downloaded TortoiseSVN and inspected the solution - turns out I had a tree conflict with one of my folders that had been renamed - logged into the VisualSVN Management server and deleted the "old" (original named) folder directly and pulled an update.

The next issue I discovered was the "obj" folder had somehow crept into the mix which was causing problems as visual studio loves updating files in here and so there were ALWAYS files to commit. Used TortoiseSVN to "Unversion and add to ignore list" on all the obj folders (Have about five projects in the solution that this had happened to!) and committed.

Once these steps had been taken I was able to update within Visual Studio using AnkhSVN and then use the AnkhSVN merge wizard to pull the changes from Trunk to Branch.